# I'm just a whisper. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I've made several friends along my way.
>   Some of them I've changed.
>   I like to think I help them find their voice.
>
> Sally, for instance, had an insulting serpent's tongue.
>   With my help, she became calming.
>
> William resisted change. However, in some cases,
>   I was able to influence whomever was near us.
>
> Timothy and I got along quite famously indeed.
>   When we befriended the popular kid, they wrote an article about it.
>
> Caroline and I are also a power couple.
>   Trains and even some places of worship have echoed our work.
>
> I tried to make friends with Kevin,
>   but I may as well have just left him alone.
>
> Paul is consistently useful.
>   When we go places plus one, we can talk to anybody.
>
> Gabby, it seems, has a mind of her own.
>   It's tough to predict what we'll end up doing together!
>
> Surely there are cases in which I am unneeded.
>   I just hope I'm helping them all say what they mean.
>   Because all alone, I'm just a whisper.

---

**Who am I?**

Comment: Cf. http://www.lieder.net/get_text.html?TextId=113259 from nearly 200 years ago...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I had no idea this existed. I suppose the last line and the solutions matches up, but I feel that the content is different enough. If I were to look hard enough, I could probably find a riddle like this for every rot13(yrggre)

Comment: Oh yes, I wasn't suggesting this was plagiarism or anything like that! (Though the similarity of the last line did make me wonder whether you might have been _inspired_ by it.)

Comment: haha, I can see why! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> the letter **H**

Sally, for instance, had an insulting serpent's tongue.
With my help, she became calming.

> The sibilant S becomes the shushing SH

William resisted change. However, in some cases,
I was able to influence whomever was near us.

> W+H - often doesn't change sounds, but sometimes is the difference between, say, wore and whore

Timothy and I got along quite famously indeed.
When we befriended the popular kid, they wrote an article about it.

> T+H are paired frequently.  With the popular kid, E, give the article "the"

Caroline and I are also a power couple.
Trains and even some places of worship have echoed our work.

> C+H are also coupled often.  CHoo-CHoos and CHurches.

I tried to make friends with Kevin,
but I may as well have just left him alone.

> K+H is not seen all that often, and really doesn't change pronunciation at all.

Paul is consistently useful.
When we go places plus one, we can talk to anybody.

> P+H are paired frequently.  Add ONE and you get "phone".

Gabby, it seems, has a mind of her own.
It's tough to predict what we'll end up doing together!

> G+H can have different sounds; for example, in "cough" vs "ought" vs "ghost" vs "hiccough" vs "Edinburgh"

Surely there are cases in which I am unneeded.
I just hope I'm helping them all say what they mean.
Because all alone, I'm just a whisper.

> Alone, H is just an exhalation.

Comment: Bingo! Glad all the examples all turned out as expected this time